# Help with a double limit $x(x^2+y^2)/y$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x}{y}\sin (x^2+y^2)$$
I started with making the change $\sin\alpha  \approx   \alpha$ which is valid for $\alpha$ near zero. Therefore,
$$ L= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x(x^2 + y^2)  }{y}  $$
But now I am stucked. I tried to study the limit along the line $y=mx$ and parabola $y=mx^2$ but in both case, the limit is not different and so I cannot end. Changing the variable into polar coordinates $x= r \cos \theta$, $y=r \sin \theta$ doesn't work too.

Please, any help or advice is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course, $y=0$ is not in the domain. What if you approach the origin along the curve $y=x^3$? What is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}?$$

Comment: @zkutch Um, you have that backwards?

Comment: @zkutch Thanks, I feel stupid now... It was easy actually.

Comment: Senna. Slow down. It's wrong. You'll feel worse when you check whether that inequality is correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Taking $y=x^3$ gives that limit you wrote which is equal to 1

Comment: Well, it's almost that limit. You still have a little work to do. Carefully write up an answer when you have it. :)

Comment: Oh dear... the inequality is the opposite!! Thanks @TedShifrin I'm trying to figure out your approach

Comment: Ok, It's done! Thanks for your advice! @TedShifrin

Comment: No big deal @zkutch, but next time double-check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist, as approaching the origin by $t\mapsto(t,t^3)$ we get

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t\sin(t^2+(t^3)^2)}{t^3}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(t^2+t^6)}{t^2}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^2+\mathcal{O}(t^6)}{t^2}=1$$

but approaching the origin by $t\mapsto(t,t)$ we get

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t\sin(t^2+t^2)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\sin(2t^2)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks. Lorago, since you are active now. I have a quick doubt. Is this correct? Since $\sin t \approx t$ as $t\to 0$, $$\lim \frac{\sin x \sin y - xy}{x^2+y^2} = \lim \frac{xy-xy}{x^2 + y^2} = \lim \frac{0}{x^2 + y^2} = 0 $$

Comment: @Senna Well $\sin x\sin y$ and $xy$ are not equal, so it's not entirely correct, but the intuition should be. First order expansions of the sine function should do the trick (i.e. pretty much the same thing I do in my answer when I compute the first limit)

Comment: @Senna If you want more details, you should post it as a separate question, as it's not really related to this question